# Multiple GET/POST requests in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am having a bit of difficulty understanding why my console logs multiple GET requests for the same call:

This is my **BookCtrl**:

```
$scope.addbook = function IndexCtrl() {
    $http.get('/api/books').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.books = data.books;
    });
}
```

This is my **routes.js:**

```
app.get('/api/books', books.findBook);
```

In the console I can see the GET request multiple times:

```
GET /api/books - - ms - -
...
GET /api/books - - ms - -
...
GET /api/books - - ms - -
...
GET /api/books - - ms - -
```

Same goes for POST request:

```
POST /api/books - - ms - -
POST /api/books - - ms - -
POST /api/books - - ms - -
POST /api/books - - ms - -
```

Comment: What do you mean by what is it doing? I am trying to look up a book using amazon product API.

Comment: I have noticed it happening twice when i make a request in my maincontroller maybe it has something to do with it but 4 times seems weird

Comment: Angular could be doing something funny. Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `$http.get` or putting a console.log there?

Comment: Show how function is called. Probably not accounting for angular digest cycles

Comment: You need to call this function using ng-init to stop it being called multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean by call the function using ng-init?